# Flask Restful api post data with image

Tags: python-3.x, flask, file-upload, flask-restful

I am implementing a module where user have to put some data and upload an image. Right now I make two restful apis one for data like (name, address) etc and another one for uploading image. But i want to make one api for data with uploading image.